How parallel::mclapply pre-schedules the tasks?
I have a question about how the parameter, mc.preschedule, of parallel::mclapply works.
If I set mc.preschedule = TRUE, what is the sequence that mclapply cut the jobs into chunks?
I want to set mc.preschedule = TRUE to make it quicker, cause I have about 1000 jobs to run, but the load of each job is not that consistent, so if all the fast jobs are assigned to the same core, with mc.preschedule = TRUE, the cores are not fully utilized.
How can I use mc.preschedule = TRUE and avoid to assign the fast jobs to the same core at the same time?

Did you notice that mc.preschedule = TRUE is actually the default setting?

yes, that is default. I want to know how mcapply split the jobs into chunks and assign them to different nodes. Cause I want to use mc.preshcedule = TRUE and avoid to assign the fast jobs to the same core( in that case the cores will finish the prescheduled jobs very fast and not be fully utilized)
